# Question about closed-form of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

my question is about the below series:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n (1+x_i)^{-1}$$
and $x_i$ are n variables.
Does it have a closed-form? or a simple form?

I would be appreciated if anyone can help me.

Comment: How could it possibly have a closed form? The sum of an arbitrary collection of non zero numbers???

Comment: I need to simplify it as much as possible, is there any way? any trick?

Comment: The finite sum of reciprocals is already as simple as it gets.

Comment: Yes, but I want to convert the negative power to something in a simple shape.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p(x)= (x + x_1)(x+x_2)\cdots (x+x_n).$ Then by taking logarithms and differentiating we have

$$ \frac{p'(x)}{p(x)} = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x+x_i}$$

So your sum is $p'(1)/p(1)$.

Comment: Thank you so much, I try to use your trick in my main problem, I hope it can solve my problem